# excel 2007 can't switch to design mode

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert a basic command button on my worksheet. However, the design mode button is not working. It does not stay on after I press it. It doesn't do anything. So I can't access the properties of the button and assign code to it. Please help!!

Comment: Try and record a macro then edit the macro.  Sometimes this will allow you to get into design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on these:

- According to the image the `Design Mode` is on
- Where you can click on the button and add a code to be triggered on it's `on click` event
- Click on the Orange Design Icon to Exit the Design Mode
- Now if you click on your button, it should call your function/sub accordingly

[image]